# Rails convert to currency question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is the code I'm using to display the price of a 'property':

```
<%= number_to_currency(@property.price) %>
```

what I'm looking to do is to divide the result of this number_to_currency conversion by 4 to get a weekly price (rather than a monthly price)

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%= number_to_currency(@property.price/4) %>`

Does that not work?

Comment: yes it did. thanks. I was trying: (number_to_currency(@listing.price))/4 which didn't work. a syntax mistake on my part. thanks for your answer!

Comment: if you where trying to do the number_to_currency(@property.price)/4 you where trying to divide the string.   The other option would be to define a virtual attribute in your model called weekly price that returns price/4.